# Unusual Caro-Kann Variation

Tags: opening, caro-kann, 1.e4, pirc-defense

I'm looking for information about the unusual Caro-Kann variation that appears to be a sort of Pirc. I recently ran across this line and I'm struggling to understand why you would deviate from 2... d5.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c6
2. d4 d6
```

I can't seem to locate any information on this unusual line. Book suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Its likely a transposition to the Pribyl defense.  1. e4 d6 2. d4 nf6 3. nc3 c6 where black plays e5 at some point.

Its covered in a few books about 1 .. d6 lines where black does not play g6. Also it can transpose to the Old-Indian defense when white plays c4.

Answer (score 2):

There is a line of the Pirc, the Ufimtsev-Pytel Variation, that includes these moves after 1.e4 and 2.d4:

```
[FEN ""]
[White "Pirc Defense"]
[Black "Ufimtsev-Pytel Variation"]

1. e4 d6 2. d4 Nf6 (2... c6 3.Nc3 (3.c4! {taking advantage of Black's move order to install another center pawn} Nf6 4.Nc3 {may transpose to a Classical KID after ...g6 and ...Bg7, with or without the Kazakh move ...Na6 thrown in}) Nf6 {transposes}) 3.Nc3 c6
```

But if Black omits 2... Nf6, then there's no pressure for White to play 3.Nc3.  In fact, 3.c4 seems best, taking advantage of Black's omission, and only playing Nc3 in reply to ... Nf6, after that.

Answer (score 0):

It was not ever a Caro.  It was the start of one of many less used defenses.  Often I see it turn into a variation of the hedgehog.  Sometimes it becomes a kings indian.